# Take my kick /punch

Tags: word-usage

As you see in the picture, the blonde woman is kicking another woman in the stomach.

[image]

Can the blonde woman say:

Take my kick.

(I mean that she wants to give her kick to another woman and she humorously offers the other woman to receive her kick)

[image]

And what is your opinion about this picture?
Can the African woman say:

Take my punch.

If these sentences are not correct, what would a native speaker suggest?

Thank you .

Comment: Which one is the African woman?

Comment: The woman who has black hair and she is dark skinned. In the first picture, she is being kicked. And in the second picture, she is punching the blonde woman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may know, the expression that is commonly used (to the point of cliché) is [**"Take that!"**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-that)

> said as someone ​hits someone ​else, ​especially in ​humorous ​films or ​cartoons (--Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

I don't quite see the humour myself, but I can't see why you shouldn't adapt it a bit:

> Fighter A: "Take that!"
>
> Fighter B: "Thanks, now take this!"

To my ear, "Take my kick/punch!" is very awkward. "Take my foot/fist!" would sound slighly more natural, if you must.

Answer (score 1):

Scene 1: Take that, bitch! [Assuming this is a mature audience; otherwise, exchange "bitch" with "freak," "you evil witch," or "you monster"].

Scene 2: Right back at you!
(black woman triumphant)

Scene 3: That's what *you* get

Your stated phrasing is awkward and would definitely need to be changed to be commercially prepared for English-speaking audiences